# Iterate over array of array

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays like the following:

```
=> [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
```

I want to rearrange it by order of elements in the inner array, e.g.:

```
=> [[1,6,11],[2,7,12],[3,8,13],[4,9,14],[5,10,15]]
```

How can I achieve this?

I know I can iterate an array of arrays like

```
array1.each do |bla,blo|
  #do anything
end
```

But the side of inner arrays isn't fixed.

Comment: What should happen when an inner array is a different size? Should `nil` be inserted in the transposed arrays for shorter inner arrays?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't completely clear. Inner array doesn't have a fixed size, but they all always have the same size.

Comment: ok, I understand. If they are all always the same size, `transpose` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method on `Array`

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
a.transpose
#=> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

Note that this only works if the arrays are of all the same length.

If you want to handle transposing arrays that have different lengths to each other, something like this should do it

```
class Array
  def safe_transpose
    max_size = self.map(&:size).max
    self.dup.map{|r| r << nil while r.size < max_size; r}.transpose
  end
end
```

and will yield the following

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15,16]]
a.safe_transpose
#=> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15], [nil, nil, 16]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]].transpose
#=> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```